# Will Software/Video Game Piracy be not Haram, If the Successful product's development has been stopped by the publisher?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, piracy

I want to download a Video Game, which can be downloaded from some websites, which had a Price Tag of **$60** US Dollars... But it's development stopped and the **publishers made a Good Amount of royalty selling it** and now they are focusing on some new project, so **they have made the money they wanted by Developing that specific Software/Video Game**.. Now, If I Download a pirated copy of that Software/Video Game will it be Haram? Note, the Publisher has the Copyright of that Software/Video Game for a 100 Years! But, I can't stay that long... Now, If I download that software will it be **Haram or Maqruh**???